# Weird behaviors of css floating element

Tags: css, css-float

I am really confused about css float rules. 
Can someone explain **the mechanism behind** this, **not just solution** to make them look better. Here is the code I have:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> -->
<style type="text/css">
    div{
        width:400px;
    }
    ul{
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    li{
        float: left;
        margin: 4px;
    }

</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <ul>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x50&text=1"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x200&text=2"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x120&text=3"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=4"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=5"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=6"/></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the result:

[image]

Why on earth the 4th element goes under 3rd element but not the 1st element?

Comment: This is generally the behavior you want as mentioned by BoltClock's specs.  If this is not the desired behavior than you could add a clear style on your element to not adhere to this general CSS rule.

Comment: When float is not the solution, ou may look at column css :`ul{
        list-style-type: none;
      column-width:100px;
      column:3;
    }` or display

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#float-position) says:

> 2. If the current box is left-floating, and there are any left-floating boxes generated by elements earlier in the source document, then for each such earlier box, either the left outer edge of the current box must be to the right of the right outer edge of the earlier box, or its top must be lower than the bottom of the earlier box. Analogous rules hold for right-floating boxes.

And:

> 8. A floating box must be placed as high as possible.

Since all of your elements are floating to the left, the 4th element cannot float to the left of the 2nd element because the 2nd element comes before it in the source. The highest it can go while still remaining within the constraints of your container and its preceding floats is underneath the 3rd element because it's shorter than the 2nd element in terms of height. Therefore the 4th element floats underneath the 3rd element.

Comment: I have modified the height of 1st element to 50px, still 4th element goes under 3rd. edited the post.

Comment: @Blake: My bad, I edited the answer. This edit addresses both the original question and your edited question.

Comment: thanks! now the 3rd is not the shortest, maybe you should edit that in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As floating elements need width defined and a height in your case..
Try this..
http://jsfiddle.net/w8eDc/

```
div{
    width:400px;
}
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow:hidden;
}
li{
    float: left;
    margin: 4px;
    width: 105px;
    height:210px;
}
```

Comment: The width and height are already given by the `img` elements.

Answer (score -1):

It is because of the `size` of second box. Take a look at following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GD8tL/2/

```
 div{
        width:450px;
    }
    ul{
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    li{
        float: left;
        margin: 4px;
    }



<div>
        <ul>
            <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=1"/></li>
            <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=2"/></li>
            <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=3"/></li>                <br/>
            <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=4"/></li>
            <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=5"/></li>
            <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=6"/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```